# Correct way to control user's input (change-event is refired)

Tags: javascript, onchange

I'm trying to correct a user's input, change it (if it is not correct) and send a request with the information to the server. Currently the structure is looking like this:

```js
$(".groupsInput").change(function() {
    var elem = $(this);

    $.getJSON("...").done(function(data) {
        // do check here, if something is wrong:
        elem.removeItem(...);
    }

    $.get("..." + elem.val());   // updates the server
}
```

The problem is, that the final get-Request is triggered multiple times. I guess, that it's due to the line with `elem.removeItem(...);`. I think that the change-event here is triggered again. So, I believe that my approach is not correct. Can you tell me what the correct way would be here?

EDIT: Maybe there is something like event.cli (coming from assember here, where interrupts are disabled)? :-)

Comment: ever consider `onKeyUp` rather than changed? As you say, it'll fire if it changes itself.

Comment: The problem is, that it isn't a ordinary input-field, so onKeyUp would fire to often. Actually I am using bootstrap's tagsinput library (see here http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ )

Comment: you can add a delay to the onKeyUp so that the API is only requested when they are done typing... say like after 500ms of no typing.

Comment: That would work, not like I thought/wanted but well. If that's the way :) Thanks for answering that fast!

Comment: It's not working... seems like to be a problem with the tagsinput-library I'm using. Is there another approach? It looks like I have to register a onChange-event